# Multiple ComponentDiscoveryService in AndroidManifest --> merge conflict

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine

I am using Unity 2018.1.0f2 and Firebase 5.0.0.
Android NDK/SDK is installed as well as Java 8 172.
I already did a force resolve for android
The quick starter project for Firebase messaging runs well, however, if I try to implement firebase messaging in the same way into my project the following error is  thrown:

```
> Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, E:\path\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.firebase.firebase-measurement-connector-impl-16.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml:10] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/service[@name=com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService] element:

0x00000001414F00A9 (Unity) StackWalker::GetCurrentCallstack 0x00000001414F66B6 (Unity) StackWalker::ShowCallstack 0x000000014138F54B (Unity) GetStacktrace 0x0000000140888ADC (Unity) DebugStringToFile 0x0000000141F886A8 (Unity) DebugLogHandler_CUSTOM_Internal_Log 0x0000000052EE344B (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:Internal_Log (UnityEngine.LogType,string,UnityEngine.Object) 0x0000000052EE3334 (Mono JIT Code) [DebugLogHandler.cs:9] UnityEngine.DebugLogHandler:LogFormat (UnityEngine.LogType,UnityEngine.Object,string,object[])  0x0000000052EE2C35 (Mono JIT Code) [Logger.cs:47] UnityEngine.Logger:Log (UnityEngine.LogType,object)  0x0000000052EE2953 (Mono JIT Code) [Debug.bindings.cs:117] UnityEngine.Debug:LogError (object)  0x000000004BE988E0 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner:RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext) 0x0000000052EB7664 (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessAndroidPlayer:PostProcess (UnityEditor.BuildTarget,string,string,string,string,string,string,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry,UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport) 0x0000000052EB613A (Mono JIT Code) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidBuildPostprocessor:PostProcess (UnityEditor.Modules.BuildPostProcessArgs,UnityEditor.BuildProperties&) 0x0000000052EB5822 (Mono JIT Code) [PostprocessBuildPlayer.cs:285] UnityEditor.PostprocessBuildPlayer:Postprocess (UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,string,string,string,int,int,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,UnityEditor.RuntimeClassRegistry,UnityEditor.Build.Reporting.BuildReport) 0x0000000052EB5C6E (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) <Module>:runtime_invoke_void_int_int_object_object_object_int_int_int_object_object (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) 0x00007FF8C318668F (mono) [mini.c:4937] mono_jit_runtime_invoke  0x00007FF8C30D8A95 (mono) [object.c:2623] mono_runtime_invoke  0x0000000140BDDC2A (Unity) scripting_method_invoke 0x0000000140BD67F0 (Unity) ScriptingInvocation::Invoke 0x0000000140D5A82F (Unity) CallMono 0x0000000140D653E0 (Unity) PostprocessPlayer 0x0000000140D5DC29 (Unity) DoBuildPlayer_PostBuild 0x0000000140D5D3CC (Unity) DoBuildPlayer 0x0000000140D50787 (Unity) BuildPlayer 0x00000001415164A0 (Unity) BuildPipeline_CUSTOM_BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck 0x000000004BE317E7 (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper managed-to-native) UnityEditor.BuildPipeline:BuildPlayerInternalNoCheck (string[],string,string,UnityEditor.BuildTargetGroup,UnityEditor.BuildTarget,UnityEditor.BuildOptions,bool) 0x000000004BE30E30 (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:165] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow/DefaultBuildMethods:BuildPlayer (UnityEditor.BuildPlayerOptions)  0x000000004BE2D48B (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindowBuildMethods.cs:89] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:CallBuildMethods (bool,UnityEditor.BuildOptions)  0x000000004BE2CDEC (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:181] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun (bool)  0x000000004BE2C98C (Mono JIT Code) [BuildPlayerWindow.cs:175] UnityEditor.BuildPlayerWindow:BuildPlayerAndRun ()  0x00000000008F11DE (Mono JIT Code) (wrapper runtime-invoke) object:runtime_invoke_void (object,intptr,intptr,intptr) 0x00007FF8C318668F (mono) [mini.c:4937] mono_jit_runtime_invoke  0x00007FF8C30D8A95 (mono) [object.c:2623] mono_runtime_invoke  0x0000000140BD4CF7 (Unity) CallStaticMonoMethod 0x0000000140BD4A7E (Unity) CallStaticMonoMethod 0x0000000140D5732F (Unity) BuildPlayerWithLastSettings 0x00000001415B8EC1 (Unity) ResourceDrivenMenus::Execute 0x000000014133EDC8 (Unity) MenuController::ExecuteMenuItem 0x00000001415C49E5 (Unity) ProcessMainWindowMessages 0x00000001415A1DF5 (Unity) ContainerWindow::ContainerWndProc 0x00007FF8EE2B6CC1 (USER32) CallWindowProcW 0x00007FF8EE2B6693 (USER32) DispatchMessageW 0x00000001415C4261 (Unity) MainMessageLoop 0x00000001415C65DC (Unity) WinMain 0x000000014271FDA7 (Unity) __scrt_common_main_seh 0x00007FF8EE913034 (KERNEL32) BaseThreadInitThunk 0x00007FF8EF361431 (ntdll) RtlUserThreadStart
```

Edit: additional stack trace

```
CommandInvokationFailure: Unable to merge android manifests.  C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_172\bin\java.exe -Xmx2048M
-Dcom.android.sdkmanager.toolsdir="E:/AndroidSDK\tools" -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -jar "E:\Program Files\Unity\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer/Tools\sdktools.jar"
-

stderr[ Error: [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, E:\path\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.firebase.firebase-measurement-connector-impl-16.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml:10] Trying to merge incompatible /manifest/application/service[@name=com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService] element:   <service
      @android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService">
      <meta-data
--        @android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar" <service
      @android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService">
      <meta-data
++        @android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar" ] stdout[ [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, E:\path\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-core-ui-26.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:6] Skipping identical /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=android.support.VERSION] element. [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, E:\path\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-core-utils-26.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:6] Skipping identical /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=android.support.VERSION] element. [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, E:\path\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-fragment-26.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:6] Skipping identical /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=android.support.VERSION] element. [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, E:\path\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-media-compat-26.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:6] Skipping identical /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=android.support.VERSION] element. [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, E:\path\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.android.support.support-v4-26.1.0\AndroidManifest.xml:6] Skipping identical /manifest/application/meta-data[@name=android.support.VERSION] element. [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, E:\path\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-impl-16.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml:15] Skipping identical /manifest/application/service[@name=com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementService] element. [Temp\StagingArea\AndroidManifest-main.xml, E:\path\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.firebase.firebase-analytics-impl-16.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml:12] Skipping identical /manifest/application/receiver[@name=com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurementReceiver] element. ] exit code: 1 UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommandInternal (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) UnityEditor.Android.AndroidSDKTools.RunCommand (System.String javaExe, System.String sdkToolsDir, System.String[] sdkToolCommand, Int32 memoryMB, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr)
```

I looked over all the android manifests and found two same declarations in

E:\path\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.firebase.firebase-iid-16.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.iid.Registrar"
        android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
</service>
```

and

E:\path\Temp\StagingArea\android-libraries\com.google.firebase.firebase-measurement-connector-impl-16.0.0\AndroidManifest.xml

```
<service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" >
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.components:com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.AnalyticsConnectorRegistrar"
        android:value="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentRegistrar" />
</service>
```

Is there a way to fix this by myself, am I missing something or is this a firebase bug?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution behind this seems to be the package name variable, which unity won't replace by the actual package name in the latest builds.
https://forum.unity.com/threads/android-gradle-cannot-read-packagename-from-gradleout-src-main-androidmanifest-xml.524587/ proposes a temporary fix, by renaming the `package="${applicationId}"` variable inside the
 `"\Assets\Plugins\Android\AndroidManifest.xml"` on line 4 with the actual package name
e.g :  `package="com.MyCompany.MyGame"`

The firebase team is now aware of the problem with the 2018 build and will release a fix soon

Comment: There is no applicationId reference inside AndroidManifiest files.

Comment: Hello ebrahim, I updated my answer to make things more clear. Does this new information help you?

Comment: I've tried to remove the conflicts at manifests of staging area.I tried to remove one each of a time.. didn't work. I tried to remove all of those 2 and still didn't work.
I think the problem comes from com.google.firebase.firebase-measurement-connector-impl-16.0.1.aar and it is irrelevant to the staging area because it's data comes from libraries and scripts and in general assets.

Comment: I have same situations. I'm trying to add firebase 5.0.0 auth in clean empty project and still have same problem.

Comment: There is no AndroidManifest.xml in Assets\Plugins\Android folder  and there is no ${applicationId} in any of those AndroidManifest.xml files.

Answer (score 0):

I found

```
<service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService" >
```

in 3 aar files, you can see in image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q84Fs.png)

I merge the all service tag above into one android manifest file and delete in other [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ITWmu.png) then unity can build APK ok.
I use Unity 5.6.4p3 and Firebase Realtime Database SDK 5.0.0

I hope this can help someone, sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

After taking an entire week from me, I Found it. The problem is not relevant to the SDK minimum version or something else in this case. There was an issue and I reported it to the firebase team, at the time of writing this answer they released **Firebase 5.1.0** and it is working fine.

> SOLUTION: Build your game with Gradle builder in build options, Internal
>   unity builder is not working.

Comment: I'm trying Java 1.8.0_172 and updated AndroidSDK with Unity 2018.1.5f1

Answer (score 0):

The Firebase Unity [5.2.0](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/unity#5.2.0) SDK integrates [Play Services Resolver 1.2.79](https://github.com/googlesamples/unity-jar-resolver/blob/master/play-services-resolver-1.2.79.0.unitypackage) which fixes this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Your APK file can contain just one `AndroidManifest.xml` file, but your Android Studio project may contain several, provided by the main source set, build variants, and imported libraries. So when building your app, the Gradle build merges all manifest files into a single manifest file that's packaged into your APK.

See [Merge multiple manifest files](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/manifest-merge)