# How to use Firebase component Discovery service in On-demand feature module

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-manifest, dynamic-delivery

If I add firebase.ComponentDiscoveryService in AndroidManifest.xml of the on-demand module,

```
<service android:name="com.google.firebase.components.ComponentDiscoveryService">
</service>
```

When I launch the app, it immediately crashes. Stating,
`App has crashed.     java.lang.NullPointerException: Firebase Messaging component is not present`

Comment: Welcome, please read this [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also, I suggested to read this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50841255/multiple-componentdiscoveryservice-in-androidmanifest-merge-conflict)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.